# Multer is not saving the files

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm relatively new to learning Node.js and Express, and I've recently started using the Multer package to handle file uploads. I'm encountering an issue while attempting to save incoming image files to the 'images' folder, and despite my efforts, it's not working as expected.

controller:

```
const path = require("path");

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const csrf = require("csurf");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const multer = require("multer");

const errorController = require("./controllers/error");
const User = require("./models/user");

const MONGODB_URI =
  "mongodb+srv://Priyansh16:MongoPass123@cluster0.s3m1ro1.mongodb.net/shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const app = express();
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: MONGODB_URI,
  collection: "sessions",
});
const csrfProtection = csrf();

// Config object for multer.
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "views");

const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");
const shopRoutes = require("./routes/shop");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Multer Middleware
app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage }).single("image"));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "my secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
  })
);

// CSRF Middleware
app.use(csrfProtection);

// Flash Messages
app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.session.user) {
    return next();
  }
  User.findById(req.session.user._id)
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return next();
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new Error(err);
    });
});

// Locals
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});

// Routes
app.use("/admin", adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

app.get("/500", errorController.get500);

app.use(errorController.get404);

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.redirect("/500");
});

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI)
  .then((result) => {
    app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNvJQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that ":" is not allowed in a Windows file name. The following works:

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + file.originalname);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In Multer middleware Instead of

```
app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage }).single("image"));
```

Write:

```
  const upload = multer({
      storage: fileStorage,
  });
```

Route for image upload:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
   // req.file is your image 
   // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Don't forget the enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" />
</form>
```

[Multer Docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)